# Collecting system data from Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, shell, python-3.x, operating-system

I am planning to write a small program .The input for this should be the IP,username,password for a Linux machine ,and it should give me the system details of that machine as output.

I am planning to write this using Shell ,using RSH for the login .  I am in no way asking for a solution ,but could you please point me towards other options that I have ? I am not really comfortable using Shell scripts .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a same demand. and what i do is:

first write a script which will be executed at target host (T). something like this

```
> cat check_server.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# execute at target host

all_cmd=(
"uname -a"
"lscpu"
"free -m"
)

function _check {
    for one_cmd in "${all_cmd[@]}"; do
        echo -e "\n\n$one_cmd" >> /tmp/server_info.txt
        eval "$one_cmd" >>  /tmp/server_info.txt
    done
}
```

then execute it in target and copy back result, like this

```
_cmd=`base64 -w0 check_server`
ssh $user@$ip "echo $_cmd | base64 -d | bash"
scp $user@$ip:/tmp/server_info.txt ./
```

Comment: This certainly helps  :)

Comment: Hi @dormi330  ,how are you dealing with the pasword prompt that comes after you scp . ?